# Linux - Kickstart stops with dialog about which networking device - how to avoid

Tags: linux, installation, altiris

Using a kickstart file that stops with a dialog "You have multiple
network devices on this system. Which one do you want to install through?"

The machine being configured with PXEboot has two Ethernet interfaces. What's
missing from the network entries below? I'd like this install to proceed
without asking which Ethernet interface.

PXE begins the install with DHCP, so Kickstart should already know which of
eth0, eth1, etc. to use.

Here is the Ethernet line in the `ks.cfg` file:

```
network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --noipv6
```

Any ideas appreciated.

NOTE: I have already tried the below option and it didn't work:

In pxelinux config file:

add `ksdevice=bootif`

also add "IPAPPEND 2" to the end of the file

In kickstart file, don't specify a device:
"network --bootproto dhcp"

How to force an kickstart installation to take place over a specific Ethernet device?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your network devices' names had been renamed, for example, em1, em2 ... in Dell servers.

In that case you can add `biosdevname=0` to the kernel boot arguments, that will prevent biosdevname from being invoked.